# Mock static method with no parameters in Groovy

Tags: groovy, mocking, metaprogramming

I need to mock a static method. I'm using the EMC approach described at [Mocking static methods using groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mocking+Static+Methods+using+Groovy). Like this

```
TestDaemon.metaClass.'static'.newDownloadManager = {downloadManager}
```

The method newDownloadManager has no parameters and for some reason it is not replaced. The original code is called. In debug mode I can see that the closure that I define has a parameter. May be that's the reason? How can I define a closure without parameters? Or how can I mock a static method with no parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta class changes aren't visible to Java code. Groovy can't help you to mock a static method that gets called from Java code. You will have to use something like [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) instead (or refactor the code under test).

Answer (score 2):

A closure written like that has an implicit parameter.  Write the closure with `{ -> }` syntax.  Example:

```
x = { println "foo" }
y = { -> println "foo" }

assert x.parameterTypes as List == [Object]
assert y.parameterTypes as List == []
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. Though the closure has really no parameters in this case. But the original code still called.

Comment: Actually it works in groovy code. But in the java library where it is intended to do mocking no actual code replacement occurs.

Comment: Note that if you are calling the static method though an object instance, you must modify the metaClass _before_ the object is created.  Metaclass changes to a class don't affect instances of the class that already exist.