# Unit tests in Groovy for Java code - how to mock java classes?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, mop

I'm introducing Groovy in a large project written in Java, starting (as most of guys do) with writing unit test in Groovy for Java classes.

So the problem I have is:

Imagine I have 2 Java classes, ClassA and ClassB, interacting this way:

```
public class ClassA {
  public void doSomething(...) {

    ...//something

    ClassB.invokeSomeStaticMethod((someParam);

    ...//something

  }
}
```

ClassB is service looking up some data from database. I'm testing ClassA functionality. So I would like to mock ClassB somehow, so it's invokeSomeStaticMethod() in the context of my unit test
would return mocked value for testing. As far as I understand the main problem here is that both classes are Java and hence ClassB.invoke... method is not routed thru Groovy MOP, which the Groovy Mocks are based on. Am I right? And how could I achieve what I need?

Thanks!
Mikhail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Groovy MOP won't be able to replace the call to `ClassB.invokeSomeStaticMethod(someParam)`. You can use a framework like [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) to help you mock the static method.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods, like singletons, are death to testability.  While this is a little less so in dynamic languages like Groovy, certinaly here, you've struck a classic testability issue.

The solution is to externalize your dependency, and remove the static method from `ClassB`

```
public class ClassA(ClassB classB)
{
    ClassB classB
    public void doSomething()
    {
         classB.invokeSomething();
    }
}
```

This approach has two benenfits:

- `ClassA` is nolonger tightly coupled to `ClassB`.  It can be replaced with a subclass, or a mock.
- `ClassA` now advertises it's dependency on `ClassB` for the world to know, rather that relying on runtime errors to let developers know that something is missing.

The excellent article [Singletons are Liars](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-join-new-project.html) (from the Google Testing blog) does an excellent job of exploring this concept.

Comment: What you are saying is correct but I can't change those just classes right now...That is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I though meta-programming might help, but once ClassB is called from Java code its metaClass won't work.

[Mock static method with no parameters in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081909/mock-static-method-with-no-parameters-in-groovy/5085056#5085056)